# Create multiple jQuery dropdowns/selectboxes

Tags: jquery

**This goal** is to create a script thats can be used with multiple dropdowns on the same page. The dropdowns content is various (pics, lists etc) so this topic will only focus on the dropdowns basics (open/close/style).

I build the dropdowns by using three divs and two different style-classes that toggle (depending on if the dropdown is open or not).

I am in the middle of the process of figuring out how to make only one div show at once, so if one dropdown is open and some other dropdown is clicked, the first thats opened should automaticly close (hide). I am total beginner in jQuery so all help is very appreciated, it would be great if you could leave a comment in the code so I get it and learn some.

This is how the code looks for now. I modify a script I got help with earlier.

http://jsfiddle.net/yup2s/1/

Later the dropdown also need a special function that I hope is possible to do in jQuery. When close the dropdown (I havent really made it so far yet) there should be two different options how to do it:

1: Click at label or outside the div (at the page), used when there is multiple settings in the dropdown so many clicks can be made in the dropdown before close.
2: Click at label, inside or outside the div (when div workes like a selectbox).

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yup2s/4/

For the part where "when you click one, the other close", i simply added those 2 lines in the if statement:

```
$('.style_active').siblings('[id^=drop_]').hide();
$('.style_active').removeClass("style_active");
```

Then for your second request, i added a function on the document click :

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.style_active').siblings('[id^=drop_]').hide();
    $('.style_active').removeClass("style_active");
})
```

But there is a new problem, since your dropdown is a part of the document, when you click on the, it immediately close. You need to stop pragation on dropdown click with that :

```
$("div").on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Wow you wrote more efficient code in 5 min then I have written in some hours. This is great! I will sure mess around with this code until I learn something from it. Do you maybe want to look into that little special function I mention also? I dont know if thats possible with jQuery. Thanks alot! You have helped alot.

Comment: Everything is possible with jquery, do you mean something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/yup2s/20/? If yeah, check the last function i added.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You mean just rename that class (.drop) in the last function and give that class to a "#drop_x" div?

Comment: Dont need, the last function work as long as all your option have the class drop.

Comment: Ok I think I explained badly in my first post. The basics dropdown functionality works great now, the extra function would work like this: At the moment dropdowns closes when click anywhere (at title, in dropdown, outside dropdown). What I need is a extra function for some dropdowns (not all, majority is closed as they are at the moment) so they dont close when click inside the dropdown (if there is many settings etc = many clicks), so some dropdowns only close at click to either title or outside the dropdown, the most efficient I guess would be to add a class to those. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, dropdowns works great and have the functionality I asked for. Thanks alot!

Comment: Some smal bug I cant figure out, none of the divs is closing when click outside the dropdown (at html doc) with the same code at my site.

Comment: The strage thing is that if I just copy the exact code and paste it into a HTML doc all the functionality is there except the click outside the dropdown to close it. Look at this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/yup2s/24/. With that extra code it closes with click outside ".drop" but then its not possible to close it with click at title.

Comment: I don't get what the "extra code" is doing more than the already existing code. You could remove it and everything will work fine.

Comment: I dont get it either, the script closes fine in jsfiddle but in my page (offline) its impossible to close the .drop with click outside .drop (at html page), exact same code. But when I add this code it works to close it outside, but ofcorse the script gets messed with so its not a good solution. Hmmm.

Comment: I maybe just found a "clue" to this problem, the entire page is in a wrapper. If I open a dropdown and click outside the wrapper the .drop is closing! If click inside the wrapper its not closing, can this give tell you something?

Comment: If the wrapper is a div, it enter in the `$('div').on('click')`. Maybe you should givve a class to you dropdown and use `$('dropdownClass, dropdownClass div').on(...)`

Comment: Take a look at this jsfiddle, now its the same "problem" in the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/yup2s/26/

Comment: YES! Finally that works! Thanks alot (again). Now there is only the load problem left, then its finish! I made a post about it becuse I spent the entire evening trying find the error, it strange becuse it works on all my other scipts and I cant find any error in this script, but when its getting loaded into a div with a trigger event some other scripts stop work etc. If you want take a look see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306448/script-dont-work-when-loaded-in. Thank you very much!